# Scroll inside RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, android-scroll

I have a vertical `RecyclerView` and inside every item a custom view with own horizontal scroll and scale. When I try to scroll view inside item I get scroll conflict  `RecyclerView` interrupts touch event and tries to move the list.

How can I restrict `RecyclerView`  to handle horizontal swipe event?

I tried to interrupt event via `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` and pass them directly to my custom view. That almost works but sometimes I get wrong events and scroll in the custom view does not work.

Has someone else faced this problem?

Comment: It might help answering if you added some more code what you have tried not only a name of Interface you have implemented or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use simple OnTouchListener instead OnItemTouchListener